# PHP gettext() without relying setlocale

Tags: php, localization, internationalization, gettext

Currently I need to set and restore locale on my **translate** function because if using `setlocale` globally will affecting other part of our system (i.e. legacy code)

So we need to use..

```
function translate($text, $locale) {

    $original = getenv('LC_ALL');

    putenv('LC_ALL=' . $locale);
    setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale);

    $translated = _("text);

    putenv('LC_ALL=' . $original);
    setlocale(LC_ALL, $original);

    return $translated;
}
```

Are there any better way?

Comment: Perhaps use a purely PHP based PO/MO file parser/gettext implementation which does not rely on the locale?

Comment: For example [php-gettext](https://launchpad.net/php-gettext/) via [Using PHP Gettext Extension vs PHP Arrays in Multilingual Websites?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2319192/367456)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `LC_ALL`, just use `LC_MESSAGES`. While setting `LC_ALL` will of course work, because it sets the language globally, it's perfectly enough to set only `LC_MESSAGES` - only this variable is used for translating:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US");
setlocale(LC_MESSAGES, "cs_CZ");
_("something") # you will get czech translation now, even if globally you use EN
```

So if your legacy code can handle `LC_MESSAGES` set correctly, you are fine.

See https://www.php.net//manual/en/function.setlocale.php for more information on each `LC_*` variable.

Answer (score 1):

You should pull the locale from the LANG environment variable as LC_ALL may not be set.  This may not be Windows compatable, if you need it to be let me know and I'll update it.

---

```
//default locale to use when all else fails
define('DEFAULT_LANG',    'en_US.UTF-8');

/**
 * returns the current locale based on the LANG environment variable. 
 * Only calls getenv() once, after that uses a cached value.  remove the static 
 * keyword to disable this functionality.
 * 
 * @return string returns the current locale, or DEFAULT_LANG on error.
 */
function get_lang() {
  static $lang; //static variable, so the resulting call to getenv() only fire once
  if (!isset($lang) || $lang=="") { 
    $lang = getenv('LANG');
    if (trim($lang)=='')
      $lang = DEFAULT_LANG;    
  }
  return $lang;
}

/**
 * @param string $text string to translate
 * @param string $locale locale to translate to, i.e. de_DE
 * @param boolean $provideFallback - provide the original local as a fallback if locale is not     recognized
 * @return boolean|string returns $text translated to $locale, or FALSE on error. 
 */
function translate($text, $locale, $provideFallback = FALSE, $resetLocale = TRUE) {
  if ((empty($locale) || trim($locale)=='') && !$provideFallback) 
    return FALSE;
  if (empty($text))
    return $text;

  $original = get_lang();

  //provide a fallback locale in case $locale is not recognized.
  if ($provideFallback) {
    $l = strval($locale);
    if (empty($locale) || trim($locale)=='')
      $l = $original; //set locale to the original locale, since none was provided.
    $locale = array($l, $original, DEFAULT_LANG);
  }

  setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale);
  $translated = _($text);
  if ($resetLocale) {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, $original);
  }
  return $translated;
}


echo get_lang().PHP_EOL;
echo translate("test1", "de_DE.UTF-8") . PHP_EOL;
echo translate("test2", "de_DE.UTF-8") . PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [php-gettext](https://launchpad.net/php-gettext) is an option? It's a pure PHP implementation of the gettext functionality. Its `gettext_reader` class can read a gettext .mo file without relying on the locale functionality or any other global state. (php-gettext can also provide drop-in replacements of the standard PHP gettext API, but that seems rather ugly/dangerous.)

Disclaimer: never actually used this in production.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the proper way to do that.
I had the same problem few year ago.

Here is my code, similar to yours :

```
// Translate
$_SESSION['locale'] = $locale;
\Application::GetInstance()->getLocaleManager()->refresh();
$output["data"][] = array(
    "text" => utf8_encode($menuItem->getLibelle()),
    "lang" => utf8_encode(ucfirst($localeName)),
    "translation" => utf8_encode(_($menuItem->getLibelle()))
);
// Restore lang
$_SESSION['locale'] = "fr";
\Application::GetInstance()->getLocaleManager()->refresh();
```

refresh() is doing :

- \Locale::setDefault($locale)
- setlocale(...)
- putenv("LANG=".$locale); // Required on windows environment
- putenv("LANGUAGE=".$locale); // Required on windows environment